# background-repeat not working

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple html page with an image on it to display as a header. The problem is that the image is not repeating.

When I set the `width` to `100%` the td (`side`) disappears.
If I remove `width` from `basestrip`, then it only covers half of the screen area. I want to cover all of the screen with the image with the specified height.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="side" width="10px" height="25px"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="basestrip" width="100%" height="25px">
                    </td> 
             </tr>
</table>
```

This is the css:

```
#side {
background-color: #014160;
}

#basestrip {
    background-image: url('../Images/topstripbg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
}
```

Comment: have you tried applying the background image to the `tr` element instead of the `td`?

Comment: are you laying out a website using tables?? Also, give #basetrip a width of 90% and #side a width of 8% and see whether the side stays.

Comment: also check whether image path is correct, might be its not loading image..

Comment: Aaron i have tried using tr but still same result.

Comment: Darshit it is loading an image because if i give width like in 1000 it works fine. but its bad to do it, i want to repeat the image that is why i am using repeat-x but unfortunaetly its not working.

Comment: Indranil I applied the attributes as you have said but the side doesn't stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a width="100%" (or better a style="width: 100%" or even better with applying a CSS style of width: 100%) to your table. With your code, the cell takes 100% of the table. But the table takes by default the size of the content of all the cells.

Comment: what i have done is...giving the 100% in table and setting the image in tr and rest i have applied the css.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the  element has no height property, that can be applied to the . Also you can not append the 'px' to a height or width attribute for an html tag, this only applies to CSS. I assume this table should be the width of the browser window, and 25 pixels high, 1 row with 3 cells, the first being 10px wide, the second you have not specified and the last you have 100%. Here is my cross browser approach:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #thetable { width:100%; height:25px; }
      #thetable>tr { height: 25px }
      #thetable>tr>td#side { width: 10px }
      #thetable>tr>td#basestrip { background: url('../Images/topstripbg.png') repeat-x; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="thetable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td id="side" width="10"></td>
        <td width="auto"></td>
        <td id="basestrip" width="100%"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

take that property like this

```
#basestrip { background: url('../Images/topstripbg.png') repeat-x;    }
```